# Undefined index: is_rotate

Tags: php

Всем привет, помогите разобраться, весь день искала ответ, ничего не нашла, при попытке загрузить дополнительное фото в товаре возникает предупреждение:

> Notice: Undefined index: is_rotate in /var/www/u0522611/data/storage3/modification/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 232
>   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/u0522611/data/www/gel-travel.online/admin/controller/startup/error.php:34) in /var/www/u0522611/data/www/gel-travel.online/system/library/response.php on line 36

Заранее большое спасибо. 
 Версия OpenCart 3.0.3.2

Кусок кода из файла product.php

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_image WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    if (isset($data['product_image'])) {
        foreach ($data['product_image'] as $product_image) {                
                if(isset($product_image['product_option_value_id']) && $product_image['product_option_value_id']) {
                    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_image SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', image = '" . $this->db->escape($product_image['image']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$product_image['sort_order'] . "', is_rotate = '" . (int)$product_image['is_rotate'] . "', product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$product_image['product_option_value_id'] . "'");    
                } else {                        
                    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_image SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', image = '" . $this->db->escape($product_image['image']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$product_image['sort_order'] . "', is_rotate = '" . (int)$product_image['is_rotate'] . "'");
                }                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно проанализировать элементы массива `$data['product_image']`
В каком-то из них (а может быть во всех) нет ключа `is_rotate`. Это выводит ошибку уровня `NOTICE`

```
Notice: Undefined index: is_rotate in /var/www/u0522611/data/storage3/modification/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 232
```

Т.к. Ваша конфигурация php на отображение ошибок уровня `NOTICE`, сообщение выводится на экран и скрипт продолжает работу. Где-то дальше скрипт пытается вывести заголовок и спотыкается (нельзя отправить заголовок, если какой-либо текст уже выведен) и сообщает об ошибке уровня `WARNING`

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/u0522611/data/www/gel-travel.online/admin/controller/startup/error.php:34) in /var/www/u0522611/data/www/gel-travel.online/system/library/response.php on line 36
```

Варианты решения:

- Выключить вывод ошибок уровня `NOTICE` (но это путь плохишей)
- Добавить проверку ключа `is_rotate`
- Понять, почему нет ключа `is_rotate` и искоренить проблему

Comment: подскажите как добавить проверку ключа is_rotate, в моем коде, я запуталась, не судите строго

Comment: @ЛенаДжамалиева в цикле `foreach ($data['product_image'] as $product_image) {` добавьте первой строчку `if (!array_key_exists('is_rotate', $product_image)) $product_image['is_rotate'] = 0;`
Но лучше пойти по третьему пути

Comment: спасибо помогло, про третий путь мне пока сложно думать, даже не представляю с чего начать)

Comment: @ЛенаДжамалиева Начать нужно оттуда, где присваивается значение переменной $data...

Comment: @ЛенаДжамалиева если проблема решена, закройте, пожалуйста вопрос.

Comment: как я должна это сделать?

Comment: @ЛенаДжамалиева отметить правильный ответ галочкой